# Simplest way to pass an xml file as  a store procedure parameter using  c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm looking for the simplest way to pass an xml file as  a store procedure parameter using  c#.Actually I need to create an xml file for the purpose of save this xml into the sql database.In database store procedure there has a parameter as xml type. I have already created a xml file stated bellow

```
 StringWriter stringWriter = null;
 XmlTextWriter writer = null;
 try
 {
  stringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder());
  writer = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
  writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
  writer.WriteStartDocument();
  writer.WriteComment("Holiday Info");

  writer.WriteStartElement("holidayInfo", "");

  for (int groupIndex = 0; groupIndex < numberOfGroup; groupIndex++)
        {
            for (int religionIndex = 0; religionIndex < numberOfReligion; religionIndex++)
            {
                for (int jobStationIndex = 0; jobStationIndex < numberOfJobStation; jobStationIndex++)
                {
                    writer.WriteStartElement("HOLIDAY", ""); 
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("intGroupID", chkGroupList.Items[groupIndex].Value.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("intJobTypeId", "0");
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("intJobStationID", chkReligionList.Items[religionIndex].Value.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("intHolidayID", ddlHolidayName.SelectedValue.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("dtePermitedDate", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("intReligionId", chkReligionList.Items[religionIndex].Value.ToString());
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("dteFromDate", txtFromDate.Text);
                    writer.WriteAttributeString("dteToDate", txtToDate.Text);
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                }
            }

        }
      stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
      return will be what if i want to sent this file to the store procedure parameter?;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (writer != null) writer.Close();
        if (stringWriter != null) stringWriter.Close();
    }
```

return type will be what if i want to sent this file to the store procedure as xml parameter?

This is my store Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sprHoliday_InsertHolidaysGroupPermission]
@intUserID INT =NULL,
@xmlHolidayPermissionDetails XML,
@insertStatus AS VARCHAR(200) OUT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @intEmployeeID int
IF (@intUserID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SELECT @intEmployeeID = intEmployeeID From dbo.tblUserInfo WHERE   tblUserInfo.intUserID = @intUserID       
END 

BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY
   INSERT INTO  dbo.tblEmployeeGroupPermissionHolidays
                (intGroupID,
                 intJobTypeId,
                 intJobStationID,
                 intHolidayID,
                 dtePermitedDate,
                 intReligionId,
                 dteFromDate,
                 dteToDate)
        (SELECT  xmlHolidayPermissionDetails.item.value('@intGroupID[1]', 'INT'),
                 xmlHolidayPermissionDetails.item.value('@intJobTypeId[1]', 'INT'),
                 xmlHolidayPermissionDetails.item.value('@intJobStationID[1]', 'INT'),
                 xmlHolidayPermissionDetails.item.value('@intHolidayID[1]', 'INT'),
                 xmlHolidayPermissionDetails.item.value('@dtePermitedDate[1]', 'DATE'),
                 xmlHolidayPermissionDetails.item.value('@intReligionId[1]', 'INT'),
                 xmlHolidayPermissionDetails.item.value('@dteFromDate[1]', 'DATE'),
                 xmlHolidayPermissionDetails.item.value('@dteToDate[1]', 'DATE')
          FROM   @xmlHolidayPermissionDetails.nodes('//HOLIDAY') AS xmlHolidayPermissionDetails(item)
         )
   COMMIT 
   INSERT INTO dbo.tblHRDataHistory values('Insert','Holiday Permission Data Insert','tblEmployeeGroupPermissionHolidays',GETDATE(),@intEmployeeID)
   SET @insertStatus = 'Holiday Permission has been iserted succesfully' 
 END TRY

 BEGIN CATCH
 Rollback
 SELECT @insertStatus = 'There was an error! ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
 END CATCH 

 END
```

Comment: Looks like you can just return the xml string. But you'll have to post the SP to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(string);
```

This should work.

Comment: This is the .NET 2.0 API which you should use if you're not using .NET 3.5 or above. Otherwise .NET 3.5's `XDocument` provides a nicer, LINQ-enabled API.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I've not developed anything in .NET for a while. I am kinda outdated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need a function which return type will be xml.

Comment: @yeasir007: There's no such type as just `xml` in .NET - XDocument, XElement, XmlDocument etc *are* types in XML APIs. I suspect you're confused about your own requirements.

Comment: @yeasir007 Well, I was using `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(str);
doc.Save("XML.xml");` when I was developing on C#, but as I was told it's .NET 2.0 API you can use it if you don't need the newest version.

Answer (score 3):

For a whole document:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(text);
```

If you just need an element which you can easily add to another document:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(text);
```

This is assuming you're using .NET 3.5 - LINQ to XML is much nicer than the old APIs.

Note that you've said repeatedly that you need "a function which return type will be xml". There's no such type as "xml" in .NET - but types like `XElement`, `XDocument` etc are types within XML APIs. You don't need to create a separate method to return them - they already exist as `XDocument.Parse` and `XElement.Parse`, as shown above.

I suspect you're confused about your own requirements - note that "return an xml **file**" is also a bit odd. Are you trying to *write* the data to a file? Read it from a file? What do files have to do with your requirements if not?

If you could give more details about what you're really trying to do, we may be able to help you more.

Comment: `XElement.Parse()` will handle a 'document' quite well.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Sure - will edit. My point is that if you only *want* an element, you don't need to parse it into a document first.

Answer (score 2):

The "simplest" qualifier in your question is highly subjective as different approaches can be justifiably valid. Nonetheless, here's a "simple" solution:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstring);

XElement el = doc.Root;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need a function which return type will be xml.

Comment: `XDocument` and `XElement` are strongly typed representations of XML documents and XML elements respectively - in .NET 3.5+